# How to drag div after editing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using JavaScript function that handles dragging a div and the div is also editable. But my problem starts when I write text then the div is not dragging.

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $(".draggable").draggable().click(function() {

        $(this).draggable( {disabled: false});}).dblclick(function() {

            $(this).draggable({ disabled: true });});

</script>
```

I searched many places but I didn't find any solutions. Please Help.

Comment: use if else condition

Comment: could you please create a jsfiddle with an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: check this [link](http://musicjee.com/New%20directory/index.html) this is my original application link check there.